# Is there a way to change the encoding in which the "test.txt" file is created to UTF-8 in a Batch file?

Tags: batch, batch-file

My goal was to make the "test.txt" file create it with "UTF-8" encoding instead of creating it in "ANSI".
I leave attached the whole batch file:

```
@echo off
cls

break > test.txt

pushd "C:\Users\MARKETING 1\Desktop\SHARED" || exit /B 1
for /D %%D in ("*") do (
    rd /S /Q "%%~D"
)
for %%F in ("*") do (
    if /I not "%%~nxF"=="FILES SAVED HERE WILL BE AUTOMATICALLY DELETED EVERY SATURDAY.txt" del "%%~F"
)
popd

start test.txt

echo %DATE% %TIME% >> test.txt

if %errorlevel% NEQ 1 Echo ERROR DETECTED>>test.txt
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 Echo No error detected>>test.txt

if %errorlevel% NEQ 1 (echo No errors found) ELSE (echo ERROR DETECTED)>>test.txt
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 echo No errors found || echo ERROR DETECTED>>test.txt
 
dir "C:\Users\MARKETING 1\Desktop\SHARED">>test.txt
```

The file that should have "UTF-8" encoding is the file named "test.txt".

I put a string of the batch file for you to understand better:

```
break > test.txt
```

Comment: Why do you need the `start test.txt` command?

Answer (score 2):

#### How do I create a UTF-8 encoded file from with in batch file?

Add the following line at the start of your batch file:

```
chcp 65001 > nul
```

Source: [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39978785/3536342) by [Martin Prikryl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/850848/martin-prikryl)